# Referencing column names with pg_fetch_row in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

**How can you reference column names with PHP's `pg_fetch_row`?**

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281007/to-understand-an-array-in-php-when-given-the-other-variable-in-the-array/1281015#1281015) about the code which we have been debugging with Cha.

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=noa user=noa password=123");
$result_titles_tags = pg_prepare( $dbconn, "query777",
    "SELECT question_id, title
    FROM questions
    WHERE question_id IN
    (    
        SELECT question_id
        FROM questions
        ORDER BY was_sent_at_time
        DESC LIMIT 50
    )
    ORDER BY was_sent_at_time
    DESC LIMIT 50;"
);
$result_titles = pg_execute( $dbconn, "query777", array());


while($row = pg_fetch_row( $result_titles )) {
    $question_id = $row[0];                   // This works but following does not
       // We cannot use here `$question_d = $row['question_id']      
                // Problem here: 
                // What is the reason that you cannot use $row['question_id']?
       // for some unknown reason
       //
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`pg_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php), which returns an associative array--i.e., you can call the fields by name.

[`pg_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) allows you to call them by either name or index. [`pg_fetch_object`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-object.php) allows you to refer to them as `$row->question_id`.

Choose whichever one you like best. There's no real appreciable speed difference.