# How to combine (add) two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you combine two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285391/how-can-you-combine-two-arrays)

I have variable `$data1` that contains data from database. And also variable `$data2` that contains data in the same structure. How to add two arrays? I want to have 13 rows of data (10 from first array and 3 from second array):

```
$data1=mysql_query(" SELECT info1,info2,s3 FROM my_table order by info1 desc LIMIT 1, 10 ");
$data2=mysql_query(" SELECT info1,info2,s3 FROM my_table order by RAND() LIMIT 0, 3 ");

//how add data1 and data2? $data1=$data1+$data2 ?

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data1)) { ... }
```

Comment: why dont you just do a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/union.html)? Apart from that, how to merge arrays is a duplicate. See Related section to the right.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That is better solution with UNION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_merge($array1, $array2, ...)` to merge two or more array it will return an array [read this](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php